# Windows vs Linux buffer overflow

Tags: linux, stack, overflow

I saw lots of tutorials about stack buffer overflow exploitation, but I noticed a difference between the windows and linux exploit sandwich.

Linux exploit sandwich : **nops + shellcode + return address**

Windows exploit sandwich : **nops + return address + shellcode**

My question is: Is there a difference in memory organization between windows and linux? If not, why does the exploit sandwich in linux differ from the windows exploit sandwich?

Answer (score 0):

On the general memory layout of Linux vs Windows, this is a good introductory article: http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/